# Finite State Machine controlling GUI

Tags: design-patterns, fsm

I've been working for months now on my own GUI system (in Java). I had created a turn-based-game, events can only be fired by a player or AI, *sequentially*. I created a Graph containing Cells containing *grosso modo* ScreenComponents (such as scrolling text with a prompt, images, looping animations, bounded animations). Cells were linked between themselves using a key code. It was working just fine, I thought I had a good Idea but the absence of answers from the net makes me think I did something wrong, on the paper, it's awesome because unless the player does something, so it's using nearly zero CPU.
So could someone give me the name (if there is one, I really hope so) of what I'm trying to do? I asked my teachers no one was able to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of doing work in response to user interaction or other external events is known as Event-Driven Programming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) and is standard for graphical applications, especially games.

Doing all work in the UI thread would cause things to only happen sequentially. This is OK if all of the work you need to do can be completed in a short amount of time such that it doesn't negatively affect the user's ability to interact with the application or adversely affect other processes. Often times applications will start single-threaded like this and will only be upgraded to a multi-threaded application when you start encountering heavier workloads.

That said, I would always use at least two threads for a game: one for updating the UI and receiving the initial user-input, and one more thread for the actual processing of user input and other, autonomous game events.

Comment: It is actually multithreaded, I'm using à thread for each animation or scrolling text, but it's ok because I never have more than 3 offre them active on the same frame.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it might be a tad expensive to dedicate an entire thread to individual animations/scrolling text. A more traditional way would be to break up the animations into frames with a current frame count. Then, either using a local counter or global frame counter, periodically update the frame counter (can even be done in the UI thread). Then when its time to draw in the UI thread you just load the frame image at the current counter index (mod the number of frames). 

You don't want to overuse multi-threading, as that can lead to an abundance of context switching - which is slow.

Comment: I get your point but I really don't have much animations at the same time (maybe 1 or 2), I've written it this way because I didn't initially know how many would be running at the same time in the end, so I followed the "natural" way, because how would you make it work for a first loopingAnimation defined like (47ms, 72ms, 125ms) and a second one defined like (61ms, 17ms, 190ms, 172ms)?